# Azure CLI query JMESPATH more then one expression

Tags: azure, devops, azure-cli, jmespath

I'm trying to list all unmanaged disks in a specific resource group in my account inside Azure cloud provider that not have a specific tag, but having issues with the query part.

The command above lists all unmanaged disks:

```
az disk list -g $rgName --query [?managedBy=='null'].name -o tsv
```

When writing the command above, I'm not getting any output (although I have unmanaged disks that don't have tags.Action equals to 'ToDelete':

```
az disk list -g $rgName --query "[?(managedBy=='null') && (tags.Action!='ToDelete')].name" -o tsv
```

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is because you are comparing against the string `'null'` instead of [`null`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/null.html). This will cause you to recieve an empty array `[]` as the result.

This works for me:

```
az disk list -g $rgName --query "[?(managedBy==null) && (tags.Action!='ToDelete')].name"
```